# How to iterate over a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

Edit: Apologies - after reading the comments I realized this is a dictionary of dictionaries(?)

The answer that solved this is to change it to ...price_list["market"].values() in the for loop. Thanks a lot.

Original:

I'm getting a value back from an API in this kind of format:

{'market': {'14912878': {'cost': 45695, 'quantity': 2000, 'total_cost': 91390000},...}

I'm trying to iterate over this to pull the 'cost' for each item ID (the '14912878' here, but there are many others).

Here's what I've tried, but it's saying I can't run get on a str, because it's pulling the item ID. I'm not sure how to iterate over the item IDs to pull out the 'cost' (not the total_cost).

```
price_list = [price.get('cost',0) for price in item_list["market"]]
```

I also tried to put it in a for loop:

```
for item in price_list["market"]:
     price_list = [price.get('cost',0) for price in item_list["market"][item]]
```

If anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: what is the format of the others, i see only dictionnaries, no list?

Comment: It's {'market': {...}, 'market2': {...}, ...}?
Or {'marker': {'a': {...}, 'b': {...}, ...}?

Comment: `{'market': {'14912878': {'cost': 45695, 'quantity': 2000, 'total_cost': 91390000},...}` That is a single dictionary, not a list of them.

Comment: `item_list['market']` is a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: If you want to iterate over the values in the dictionary, use `for price in item_list["market"].values()`. Without using `.values()` you're iterating over the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {
    'market': {
        '14912878': {'cost': 45695, 'quantity': 2000, 'total_cost': 91390000},
        # ... other items
    }
}

for item_id, item_data in data['market'].items():
    cost = item_data['cost']
    print(f"Item ID: {item_id}, Cost: {cost}")

# or for one-liner
costs = [item['cost'] for item in data['market'].values()]
```